Flash Write and Read
In the Page Program section of the docs for the AT25SF0818 Flash device, it says it is first necessary to erase a specified section of memory before writing to it.
Given that this is the memory layout:

My understanding is that, for example, to write 8 bits to 0FF000, I would have to erase all data in 0F0000 beforehand.
If I then wanted to read back the data written, which of the two addresses should I specify in the read signal?

You do not have to erase all data in the 64KB region beginning with address 0F0000.  You could if you wanted to, but you could limit it to erase the 4KB region starting at address 0FF000.  You also have an option to erase a 32KB region.
To read back data bytes starting at address 0FF000, you could use the "Read Array" command specifying that address (0FF000).
